# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals then $\alpha \in \beta \Leftrightarrow \alpha \subsetneq \beta$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

**Def 1.** $x$ is $\underline{transitive}$ if $\forall y \forall z (z \in y \in x \Rightarrow z \in x)$.

**Def 2.** $x$ is $\underline{ordinal}$ if $x$ is transitive and all elements of $x$ are transitive.

**Def 3.** $S(x) = x \cup \{x\}$.

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals then $\alpha \in \beta \Leftrightarrow \alpha \subsetneq \beta$.

1. $\Rightarrow$. By transitivity.
2. $\Leftarrow$. It seems that we have to take $\alpha$ and prove that $S(\alpha) \subset \beta$. $S(\alpha)$ is also ordinal if $\alpha$ was ordinal. If we can do that it will imply that ${\alpha} \in \beta$. But how to make it precisely?

Comment: I firmly believe that $\emptyset \subsetneq \{\emptyset\}$ since left set has $0$ elements and second set has $1$ element.

Comment: Is $\subsetneq$ a sign for a proper subset?

Comment: Sorry, I was completely confused. I misread $\subsetneq$ as $\not\subseteq$. I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @MJD no problems =).

Comment: Note that for the forward direction you are using the axiom of foundation to show $\alpha \ne \beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a theorem that was proved on lectures.

**Th**. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals then either $\alpha \in \beta$, or $\beta \in \alpha$, or $\alpha = \beta$.

Okay, we have that $\alpha \subsetneq \beta$. Obviously that $\alpha \neq \beta$. Suppose that $\beta \in \alpha$. Then $\alpha \subsetneq \beta \in \alpha$. But this implies that $\beta \in \beta$. Contradiction with axiom of regularity! Hence, last possible variant is $\alpha \in \beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the definition of $S(\alpha) = \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$. It suffices to show $S(\alpha)\subset \beta$. Take any $x\in S(\alpha)$. Either $x\in \alpha$ or $x=\alpha$. In the first case, $x\in \beta$, because $\alpha \subset \beta$ as $\beta$ is an ordinal. In the second case $x=\alpha$, so $x\in\beta$. Thus $S(\alpha) \subset \beta$.

Comment: Ehm... Why if $x = \alpha$ then $x \in \beta$? Isn't it a cyclic proof?